# Bluetooth suddenly stops working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, bluez

Bluetooth randomnly stopped working once i started my laptop.

The "Adapter" tab is disabled in BluetoothManager.

This is the output for the following :

sudo systemctl status bluetooth

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: inactive (dead)

Condition: start condition failed at Fri 2019-02-08 10:45:53 IST; 1min 19s ago
           └─ ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth was not met

```
 Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

In bluetooth Manager it says there are no adapters.

Comment: Today this happened to me also :( `sudo hcitool dev` allowed me to start the service, but BT is still not working.

Comment: @FilipProcházka, unfortunately I couldn't find another way. I had to re-format as i did not have a lot of data to back up.

Comment: Disabling and enabling Bluetooth in BIOS helped. But I fear that only temporarily.

Comment: Check that the system firmware is current, and if it is not, update it. I find this helps a lot with odd laptop problems such as you describe.